# separated references

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using a style for references using bibtex, with numbering order inside the document. The references are at two different languages, Persian and Latin. I need to separate the Persian and Latin references at the end of the document, without changing their order. An example is as follow

[3] Persian reference (First Persian reference)

[5] Persian reference (Second Persian reference)

[1] Latin reference (First Latin reference)

[2] Latin reference (Second Latin reference)

[4] Latin reference (Third Latin reference)

[6] Latin reference (Forth Latin reference)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would switching to `biblatex` be an option for you?

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=32166)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in the **`alpha-persian`** style.  For more information, see
[here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/alpha-persian) please.
In the `latest version(1.2)`, which I  sent to `CTAN`, you can sort the `Persian` and `English` references to your liking.
First of all, update your `texlive` (or `miktex`) and then act as below:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=green!80!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
\lr{\cite{B02f}}
و
\lr{\cite{aliabad2004rings}}
و
\cite{aliabad2004rings,ali,whatever,B02f}
و همچنین داریم:
\lr{\cite{aliabad2004rings,ali,whatever,B02f}}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-persian}
%\bibliography{sample8}
\bibliography{sample10}
\end{document}
```

---

This is your `bibfile`: **sample10**

---

‌

```
@misc{whatever,
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{3}}{Madadpour},Ahmad ",
quotation={1},
year = {2001},
Slabel = {1},
chapter={5},
title = {Testing the effects of bibtex styles on bibliography formatting},
 murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
doi   = {01.1000/doi-0121},
madadurltest={1},
key={665},
}
@misc{B02f,
 howpublished = {How it was published},
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{4}}{Madadpour},Shapour and Madadpour , Mohamadhosain and Madadpour ,Mitra  ",
    year = {2002},
    Slabel = {2},
quotation={1},
    title = {First},
pages={13--17},
madadurltest={1},
mlabel = {$\checkmark^+$},
 murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
chapter={5},
}


@article{aliabad2004rings,
  title={reference test-Rings of continuous functions vanishing at infinity},
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{5}}{Madadpour},Alireza ",
  journal={Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae},
  volume={45},
  Slabel = {4},
  pages={519--533},
quotation={1},
  year={2004},
murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
madadurltest={1},
  publisher={Charles University in Prague, Faculty of Mathematics and Physics},
}
@article{ali,
  title={reference test-Pasting topological spaces at one point},
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{6}}{Madadpour},Mahmood ",
  journal={Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal},
  volume={56},
  Slabel = {6},
  number={4},
  pages={1193--1206},
quotation={1},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer},
url = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
}

@phdthesis{mmm,
title={فضای توپولوژی},
author={{\noopsort{2}}{رضایی علی‌آباد},علی},
journal={Kyungpook mathematical journal},
  pages={1163--1171},
LANGUAGE =     {Persian},
Slabel = {5},
madadurltest={1},
quotation={1},
murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
series = {second series},
year = {2002},
url = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
chapter={5},
 school  = {دانشگاه چمران اهواز},
}
@inbook{yu,
  AUTHOR =  {
{\noopsort{1}}{نامداری},مهرداد and کوچک‌پور,عبدعلی},
Slabel = {3},
  TITLE =  {مقدمه‌ای بر نظریه‌ی  اصولی مجموعه‌ها},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1394},
  MONTH =  {بهار},
  PAGES =  {39-43},
quotation={1},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
doi   = {322/511},
isbn = {978-600-141-173-1},
edition ={دوم},
series = {سری دوم},
number = {100},
chapter={5},
madadurltest={1},
 murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
publisher = {انتشارات دانشگاه چمران},
  note = {یک یادداشت اختیاری در این‌جا می‌توانید وارد کنید},
 address      = {آدرس منتشر کننده},
slabel = {4},
}
```

---

**And this is your `output`:**

---

### [image]

Good luck.